# apt: reinstall older version of a package without altering dependent packages

Tags: apt

I have got some problem with sound. In order to investigate the problem I tried to reinstall older version of package libasound2 (I have upgraded it recently). I typed `apt-get install libasound2=1.0.1.23-2.1` and the manager wanted to unistall lots of software I use and I don't like idea that I have to install it again.

How can I change the version of selected package without all the problem with dependent software?

Comment: Try compiling the older version against the newer libraries? Usually software is "forward compatible". You forgot to mention the distribution and distribution version you are using. This is often relevant information.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming that the old version of the package exists in a repository your `apt` is configured to talk to (e.g., you've installed a version from testing or unstable and you want the version from stable back) I would recommend using `aptitude` to mark the package for downgrading.  `aptitude` will show you if there is a conflict caused by your action and let you step through possible solutions.

It's possible that you cannot downgrade.

Comment: I have already tried it. I guess it is the only solution. However, I'm surprised so many apps (emacs, chromium, ...) depend on one library in the newest version.